# How do I override field output (twig)?

Tags: theming, 8

I have a field_category field and the field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig template is used to display the output of the field. I want to override the field link attribute.

The content of field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig is the following.

```
    {#
    /**
     * @file
     * Theme override for a field.
     *
     * To override output, copy the "field.html.twig" from the templates directory
     * to your theme's directory and customize it, just like customizing other
     * Drupal templates such as page.html.twig or node.html.twig.
     *
     * Instead of overriding the theming for all fields, you can also just override
     * theming for a subset of fields using
     * @link themeable Theme hook suggestions. @endlink For example,
     * here are some theme hook suggestions that can be used for a field_foo field
     * on an article node type:
     * - field--node--field-foo--article.html.twig
     * - field--node--field-foo.html.twig
     * - field--node--article.html.twig
     * - field--field-foo.html.twig
     * - field--text-with-summary.html.twig
     * - field.html.twig
     *
     * Available variables:
     * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
     * - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
     * - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
     * - label: The label for the field.
     * - multiple: TRUE if a field can contain multiple items.
     * - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
     *   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
     *   - content: The field item's content.
     * - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
     * - field_name: The name of the field.
     * - field_type: The type of the field.
     * - label_display: The display settings for the label.
     *
     *
     * @see template_preprocess_field()
     */
    #}
    {%
    set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
    ]
    %}
    {%
    set title_classes = [
    'field__label',
    label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'visually-hidden',
    ]
    %}
    {% if label_hidden %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div class="field__items">
          {% for item in items %}
            <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</div>
        <div class="field__items">
          {% for item in items %}
            <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```

This template outputs the following.

```
    <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
    <!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
    <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
       x field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--node--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--node--field-category.html.twig
       * field--default--field-category--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--field-category.html.twig
       * field--default.html.twig
       * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
       * field--node--field-category--insight.html.twig
       * field--node--field-category.html.twig
       * field--node--insight.html.twig
       * field--field-category.html.twig
       * field--entity-reference.html.twig
       * field.html.twig
    -->
    <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/myproject/myproject_child/templates/field/field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig' -->
      <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/1/field_category/en/teaser" class="field field--name-field-category field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden">
        <div class="field__items">
                  <div class="field__item"><a href="/myproject/insights/1" hreflang="en">Legal Services</a></div>
              </div>
      </div>

    <!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/myproject/myproject_child/templates/field/field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig' -->

    <!-- THEME DEBUG -->
    <!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
    <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
       x field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--node--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--node--field-category.html.twig
       * field--default--field-category--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--insight.html.twig
       * field--default--field-category.html.twig
       * field--default.html.twig
       * field--theme-ds-field-default.html.twig
       * field--node--field-category--insight.html.twig
       * field--node--field-category.html.twig
       * field--node--insight.html.twig
       * field--field-category.html.twig
       * field--entity-reference.html.twig
       * field.html.twig
    -->
    <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/myproject/myproject_child/templates/field/field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig' -->
      <div data-quickedit-field-id="node/1/field_category/en/teaser" class="field field--name-field-category field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden">
        <div class="field__items">
                  <div class="field__item"><a href="/myproject/insights/2" hreflang="en">Product Liability</a></div>
              </div>
      </div>

    <!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/myproject/myproject_child/templates/field/field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig' -->
```

I used the Pathauto module to generate the aliases for the category with the pattern /insights/[term:tid]. I have tried to use the question mark in the pattern to generate the path aliases like /insights?tid=[term:tid], but the question mark is not allowed by the module.

How do I rewrite the field attribute in `<div class="field__item"><a href="/myproject/insights/2" hreflang="en">Product Liability</a></div>` to make it `<div class="field__item"><a href="/myproject/insights?tid=2" hreflang="en">Product Liability</a></div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just looking for the taxonomy term in your template, it can be found on the URL object like this:

```
  <div class="field__item"><a href="/myproject/insights?tid={{ item.content['#url'].routeParameters.taxonomy_term }}" hreflang="en">Product Liability</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used `{{ kint(item.content) }}` to debug the data like below.

```
 <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div class="field__items">
          {% for item in items %}
             {{ kint(item.content) }}
             ...
             ...
```

and i got the output like below

[image]

and I've updated the template file to get the output according to my requirement.

***field--default--node--field-category--insight.html.twig***

```
    {#
    /**
     * @file
     * Theme override for a field.
     *
     * To override output, copy the "field.html.twig" from the templates directory
     * to your theme's directory and customize it, just like customizing other
     * Drupal templates such as page.html.twig or node.html.twig.
     *
     * Instead of overriding the theming for all fields, you can also just override
     * theming for a subset of fields using
     * @link themeable Theme hook suggestions. @endlink For example,
     * here are some theme hook suggestions that can be used for a field_foo field
     * on an article node type:
     * - field--node--field-foo--article.html.twig
     * - field--node--field-foo.html.twig
     * - field--node--article.html.twig
     * - field--field-foo.html.twig
     * - field--text-with-summary.html.twig
     * - field.html.twig
     *
     * Available variables:
     * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
     * - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
     * - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
     * - label: The label for the field.
     * - multiple: TRUE if a field can contain multiple items.
     * - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
     *   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
     *   - content: The field item's content.
     * - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
     * - field_name: The name of the field.
     * - field_type: The type of the field.
     * - label_display: The display settings for the label.
     *
     * @see template_preprocess_field()
     */
    #}
    {%
    set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
    ]
    %}
    {%
    set title_classes = [
    'field__label',
    label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'visually-hidden',
    ]
    %}
    {% if label_hidden %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div class="field__items">
          {% for item in items %}

          {% if item.content['#url'].routeParameters['taxonomy_term'] is defined %}

            <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}><a href="{{ base_path }}insights?tid={{ item.content['#url'].routeParameters['taxonomy_term'] }}">{{ item.content['#title'] }}</a></div>

           {% else %}

                <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>

            {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        <div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</div>
        <div class="field__items">
          {% for item in items %}
            <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
```